# Do you like to sing? Sing, sing along?

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme, knowledge

While getting ready to go grocery shopping, a song came on that inspired me to write yet another riddle. This isn't typically my style, but anyone can learn anything so long as they try and learn from their mistakes!

Can you guess which song this is?

> I'm getting sleepy, I can't stay awake;
>
> For me this is trouble, since I'm at the lake.
>
> If I don't get up, before the tide rolls in;
>
> The water you see, will go, go to my chin.

**Hint**:

> Do you remember, the fourteenth of May; I can't remember, specifically that day. As I believe, twas before I was born; during the summer of eighty-four.

**Hint**:

> It's all in my title, I can't seem to stop; my genre is famous, it's known as pop.

**Final Hint**:

> Jitterbug

As a secondary question; would you sing along? Also, a more important, tertiary question; do you have any critiques on this riddle?

Comment: Changed your username, huh?

Comment: Yeah, I figured it was more fitting to not display a large chunk of my name publicly.

Comment: @PerpetualJ your name is still in your profile description, maybe change that too then ;)

Comment: @PerpetualJ I really hope my second answer is correct, because that song is now super stuck in my head!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this song

> [Wake Me Up Before You Go-Go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake_Me_Up_Before_You_Go-Go)?

One of my *all time favourites*, so I'd be singing *and* dancing along!!

Comment: That is indeed the song! It always makes me smile when this song comes on!

Answer (score 3):

Is this song (this took a *lot* of research)

> [Around My Dream, by Silver Pozzoli](http://www.metrolyrics.com/around-my-dream-lyrics-silver-pozzoli.html)?

If so, which station were you listening to when you heard this? :D

Comment: Unfortunately, this one isn't it. However, when I heard the song I was actually just playing music from my iPhone so that's not very helpful! I'm often known as off the wall with the music I listen to as it is a large collection from the 50s to the modern age and ranges from opera to heavy metal!

Comment: Darn, I thought I was close because the alternate name is "Sing Sing Sing Along"! And that's so cool! Always nice to have diverse interests :D

Comment: An interesting fact about the song in question; it was actually based on a note in which a word was accidentally repeated (probably gave it away).

Comment: Also, that would have been a good one per the title!